# media query: smartphone-landscape is executing for iPad

Tags: html, css, mobile-browser

I have css media queries like this

```
<!-- Common Styles sheet for desktops/tablets/iPads -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smartphone.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 20px) and (max-device-width : 480px)" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smartphone-landscape.css" media="only screen and (min-width : 321px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ipad-landscape.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)" />
```

THe problem is that smartphone-landscape.css file is also executing for iPad. How can I prevent it? so smartphone-landscape only works in iPhone' landsacpe mode (and for devices of similar resolutions) but not for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to an article from Chris Coyer, here are some specific css code to target ipad only and smartphones with media queries.

For the full article: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Note the specific "device" reference for ipad only query:

```
/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

So in your case:

```
<!-- Common Styles sheet for desktops/tablets/iPads -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smartphone.css" media="only screen and (max-width : 320px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smartphone-landscape.css" media="only screen and (min-width : 321px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ipad-landscape.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-apply the stylesheet within ipad-landscape.css since the smartphone.css over writes it.